Reference to applications of QCD
Applications of QED are discussed in many textbooks (computation of various cross sections, Lamb shift).
I am looking for a reference to a discussion of applications of QCD.

Applications like explaining particle accelerator experiments? I don't think you will find any like making better cars.

e.g. etching a sentient AI supercomputer all inside a proton and propelling it close to light speed towards a nearby star system to halt their science advancement?

Astromaterial Science and Nuclear Pasta https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03646

https://pdg.lbl.gov/2024/reviews/rpp2024-rev-qcd.pdf

I don't know why there are such mean comments. He asked for applications like spectrum evaluations and cross sections. Why comment with mocking BS like the AI comment? That was a legit question

@James: No. I am looking for a reference to a concrete computation in QCD which can be verified by experiment.

@LolloBoldo it is not meant as a mocking comment, but a homage to one of the most imaginative sci-fi ideas https://www.gradesaver.com/the-three-body-problem/study-guide/summary-part-iii-sunset-for-humanity-chapters-31-35

Are you making a distinction between QCD and the strong nuclear force? The latter is ofc, nuclear physics which has many practical applications.
QCD proper explains the particle zoo (e.g the need for a color quantum number, see: the $\Omega^-$ baryon, for example.)
I don't know if color confinement is an experimental constraint, or a fundamental outcome of the QCD Lagrangian, but it ofc explains the allowed hadrons as $qqq$, $q\bar q$ and exotics.
The color factors explain some ratios of similar interactions, e.g., the famous $R_{\mu}$ in comparing the rates of:
$$ e^+e^- \rightarrow q\bar q$$
$$ e^+e^- \rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$$
And then the $ggg$-vertex explains 3-jet events.
At a more advanced level, there is factorization in deep inelestic scattering, and scaling violation. This falls under names like "next-to-next-leading order QCD", in contrast to pQCD (perturbative), which works because of asymptotic freedom.
Regarding the discovery of the Higgs Boson: it would not have been possible without understanding the background in $pp$ collisions. This is involves huge models created from many different experiments measuring quark distribution functions (we don't use wave functions) and hadronization--all constrained by QCD.
One of my go-to intros to how QCD actually works is from Professor M.A. Thomson's fantastic 2009 Michaelmas lecture series: https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout8_2009.pdf
